# How to get video download link from youtube?

Tags: hyperlink, youtube, download

I searched far and wide and came up with nothing.
Ok, that is not completely true, there are in fact tons of solutions on the Internet (even here on stackoverflow) on how to get a download link for youtube video, but not a single one of them is working anymore, since youtube seems keep changing things all the time.

What I want to do, is to write a PHP script which will be able to download video from  specified youtube page and then save it on the server in flv or mp4 format.

I can get some video information by downloading this: http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id=VIDEO_ID

But thats about it, no matter what I do, I just cannot figure out how find the link pointing to the video download.

I tried to use this link: http://youtube.com/get_video?video_id=VIDEO_ID&t=TOKEN&fmt=18&asv=2 from one more recent solution I found, but either there is something missing in it, or it's completely outdated already too.

So how can I dig out some working link for direct video download from youtube?

There has to be some way to do it, since there are some web pages out there which provide this service.

Thank you for any advices.

Answer (score -4):

I prefer RealPlayer to download videos from youtube and other video sharing sites like metacafe, funnyordie and others.  You're able to download in both mp4 or flv format, save them, and view them whenever you'd like.. even if you're not online which is great for travel. http://www.real.com/realdownloader

Comment: That is not what i asked for at all, i need to download that video via PHP so i can directly work with it on the server. Manual download via some application is of no use to me unfortunately.